# getContentAsPDF() after insert a record in the same excution context

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to insert a record in an object 'Invoice__c', after that I want to create an attachment related to this invoice. This attachment is a visualforce rendered as PDF. I have problems to call createInvoiceAttachment after createInvoice int the same execution context. In different context everything is right. What can i do?

**Exectuion**

```
Invoice__c i = Utils.createInvoice('0064E000002Jc91');
Utils.createInvoiceAttachment(i);
```

**Utils class**

```
public class Invoice {

    public static Invoice__c createInvoice(String oppId){
      Invoice__c inv        = new Invoice__c();
      inv.opp__c            = oppId;
      insert inv;
    }


    public static Attachment createInvoiceAttachment(Invoice__c inv){

      PageReference pdf = Page.InvoicePage;
      pdf.getParameters().put('id',inv.id);

      Attachment at     =   new Attachment();
      at.Body           =   pdf.getContentAsPDF();
      at.ParentId       =   inv.Id;
      insert at;
    }

}
```

Comment: what the error it is throwing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the modification you are making in the current transaction has not been committed when you make the `getContentAsPDF` call, as that call is treated as a separate transaction now. This change was delivered as a Critical Update, and that update auto-activated in January 2016. Deactivating that update as Santanu suggests is the pragmatic fix right now, but there may be a time when this change cannot be deactivated.

To fix without requiring the deactivation, you need to move the logic to a point after the transaction commits. One way is to use one of the asynchronous Apex mechanisms such as @future. Another way, if this logic is part of a controller, is to redirect back to an additional method in the controller that does the PDF generation as each controller request is a separate transaction.

Answer (score 3):

After Summer'15 release `getContent()` and `getContentAsPDF()` behave as callouts. Refer [getContent as callout](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_vf_getcontent_callout_cruc.htm#rn_vf_getcontent_callout_cruc)

According to your requirement, if you do not want to them treated as callouts then update the deactivate the entry from `Critical Update` section.

> From Setup, click Critical Updates.
>
> Click Deactivate for “PageReference getContent() and getContentAsPDF() Methods Treated as Callouts.”

Comment: This would only be a temporary solution that would last only a few months. It'd be better to fix the code so it works correctly next release.

Comment: @sfdcfox, but what will be the correct code if there is only 1 action after the insert and it is generating the pdf? I try at future but for some reason it breaks

Comment: @manza You need to use `@future(callout=true)` and make sure you do not have any DML before you do the callout in the future method (normal callout limitations).

Comment: @sfdcfox thank you so much for the comment, but what I dont understand or know how to do, is I need to do the DML before, becuase the pdf is based on the record, I have added a future method that is called after the DML so within the method there is no DML, but I think the problem is the constructor of the pdf page controller has a DML to bring the values, will this be the cause of the PDF been broken only when called from my future method? can you please give me a suggestion on how to by pass this? Thank you

Comment: @manza Consider asking a new question, and include your code. It's hard to get anything done in comments, and you shouldn't be revivifying old threads like this. We're not a forum, we're a Q&A community.

Comment: @sfdcfox thank you I will, I was trying to avoid getting complains on duplicate question

Comment: @manza Don't worry too much about the occasional duplicate flag. If you're having a legit problem, and this Q&A didn't help you, you most likely have a new (different) question. Feel free to link to this question to show your research.